# what kind of RAM is this?

Tags: memory

I have an old RAM stick I found at work along with a bunch of other old SIMM modules. It is a 30 pin module, has 5 chips on one side and 3 on the other. The chips on the module has this written on it: HM514100AZ8 Japan A0162NN. Also the module itself says BE930510. The chips appear to be made by Hitachi. I'm just trying to figure out what kind of memory it is, how old it is, what computer it goes to, etc. Thanks!!

[image: Front Side]

[image: Back Side]

Comment: This is a 30-pin SIMM with 4 MB capacity. A search turned up [this](http://search.datasheetcatalog.net/key/HM514100), which essentially states that each chip is "4,194,304-word x 1-bit dynamic RAM", so it has 512 KB capacity; eight of these chips makes 4 MB.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like those are [30-pin RAM SIMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMM#30-pin_SIMMs) for some ancient PC or Mac. I was able [to find this page on Other World Computing’s website](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/30PS16MB/) for modules that look to be the exact same form factor; pic below:

[image: Pic of an OWC30PS16MB SIMM module.]

So if you have an ancient computer—like a [Mac SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_SE), 486 PC and such—this RAM might be useful.

And FWIW, a search for the part number as [HM514100AZ-8](http://www.questcomp.com/questdetails.aspx?pn=HM514100AZ-8&utm_source=Digipart&utm_medium=industry-cpc&utm_term=HM514100AZ-8&utm_content=StandardPricing&utm_campaign=DigipartWS) shows some more details.

Comment: It's [DRAM](http://www.questcomp.com/questdetails.aspx?pn=HM514100AZ-8&utm_source=Digipart&utm_medium=industry-cpc&utm_term=HM514100AZ-8&utm_content=StandardPricing&utm_campaign=DigipartWS)

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY! After about 5 hours of searching, found out exactly what it is. They are Texas Instruments TMS-44100 80SD 4mb 30 pin SIMM RAM modules. Man, I see why they didn’t put that on the label now! Long name for something so small...